# Android GPS: "NO Location Found"

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

For some unclear reason I am not getting any locations, and onLocationChanged() is not invoked.

```
package com.example.gpsexample;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class GPS_Location extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("~~~","~~~ GPS_Location onCreate");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        Location l1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location l2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.d("~~~","~~~ GPS_Location getLastKnownLocation ==> "+l1+" "+l2);
        r.run();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("~~~","~~~ onLocationChanged "+location);

        int latitude = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int longitude = (int) (location.getLongitude());

        Log.i("~~~", "### Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude+"\n\n\n###");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("~~~","~~~ onProviderDisabled"+provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("~~~","~~~ onProviderEnabled "+provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("~~~","~~~ "+provider+" "+status+" "+extras);
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Log.d("~~~","~~~ GPS_Location run");
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("~~~","GPS enabled: "+locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
            Log.d("~~~","~~~ GPS_Location getLastKnownLocation ==> "+l);
            l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("~~~","Network enabled: "+locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
            Log.d("~~~","~~~ Network_Location getLastKnownLocation ==> "+l);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
}
```

the permissions are:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     />
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
     />
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
     />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    />
```

and the output is:

```
D/~~~     (29852): ~~~ GPS_Location run
D/~~~     (29852): GPS enabled: true
D/~~~     (29852): ~~~ GPS_Location getLastKnownLocation ==> null
D/~~~     (29852): Network enabled: true
D/~~~     (29852): ~~~ Network_Location getLastKnownLocation ==> null
```

When I change the location settings, I do see *onProviderEnabled()* calls.

***How do I get a location instead of null?***

Comment: is the location service on your device enabled? Are you sure it is connected?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your device once?

Comment: Enable location services:

settings->location and security->under my location-> select use wireless and use gps.

Comment: @GrIsHu -- restart did not help

Comment: @blackbelt -- I enabled it exactly as amalBit suggested. But what do you mean "connected"?

Answer (score 0):

```
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
```

Update Location

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Please Update In Your Code

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60 * 1, 10, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60 * 1, 10, this)
```

Comment: i think u r doing in emulater not in real decvice

Comment: i think u need lat lang of user in location change

Comment: HTC One mini, a real device

Comment: i also create many app to get lat long please indtall app and go any where and look in see Toast That Change Lat Long Are Not may Be Problem in your code genrate Toast for Location change and go to anywhere